# Using jboss resteasy (Client-side) in an OSGi Bundle for Karaf

Tags: java, maven, client, resteasy, karaf

I want to query some data for a weather forecast from https://openweathermap.org/. Since I have some experience with the jboss resteasy api, I immediatly thought I could use this api for my rest client.

However, I am struggling really hard to get it working in the karaf osgi container. After every deployment I get a ClassNotFoundException, indicating that some dependency is missing. After I manage to correctly resolve that dependency, I get another one due to all the transitive dependencies.

Currently I am getting the following Exception:

```
org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles...

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error starting bundle 223: Activator start error in bundle swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model [223].at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:66)[23:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.8]
    ... 12 more

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model [223].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2276)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:38)[23:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.8]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:64)[23:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.8]
    ... 12 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl not found by swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model [223]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.<init>(ClientWebTarget.java:40)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient.target(ResteasyClient.java:183)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at swt6.ue01.model.rest.RestModelBean.<init>(RestModelBean.java:31)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at swt6.ue01.model.WeatherForecastModelActivator.start(WeatherForecastModelActivator.java:14)[223:swt6.ue01.weather-forecast-model:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
```

I'm managing the bundle via Maven. I embbed the JARs, which are not OSGi-Bundles.
Here is the config of the maven-bundle-plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2.0)",
                        javax.ws.rs.*,
                        javax.net.ssl.*,
                        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.*,
                        com.google.guava.*
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        swt6.ue01.model;version="1.0",
                        swt6.ue01.model.impl.rest;version="1.0"
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>
                        swt6.ue01.model.WeatherForecastModelActivator
                    </Bundle-Activator>
                    <Embed-Dependency>
                        *;inline=false;groupId=!org.apache.felix|javax.ws.rs|org.glassfish.jersey.core|com.google.guava|org.glassfish.hk2
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My dependency-section is growing due to this and me knowing no better approach.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

APIs, which come as OSGi-Bundle, I simply copy to the deploy-folder of karaf via the maven-dependency-plugin

```
<artifactItem>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
</artifactItem>
```

.
.
.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After hours and hours of trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I thought I'll try to get some help online. After an unsuccessfull search, I ended up here. I appreciate every comment / answer.

Thanks, tilt